# Creating a web application with android that connects to a Microsoft Access database

Tags: android, ms-access, web

I want to create an Android application where a user can create an account which basically stores their username and password, and photos. I want to use a `Microsoft Access Database`, a user once logged in can take a photo using the android device and the photo is automatically sent to the database and stored under the user account. I don't want to use the internal SQL lite database, the whole aim of this is to store photos taken on a server as opposed to the device.

If I have an access database created on my server, is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible ( but I feel access is bad choice). Write a service on your server using either php or some other language you are comfortable, which takes input from your app and responds either xml/json.

Comment: OK, could I actually store data on my server using JSON/XML? I shall look into it now. I chose Access because it will be quicker and easier for me to develop the whole application to begin with. If this is possible with Access, do you know examples of this being done?

Thanks!

Comment: To begin with access is ok, as data get bigger you may have issues. You may start with access and when required you may switch. JSON/XML you can save, but can't do quick lookups.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider Access web services. This would mean that you publish your database to SharePoint or now office 365.

That published data becomes useable via a web service and as such would work well in disconnected mode that is typical required of a smartphone application.

The Access desktop/client application can also link to this published data (and application). And the application functions in disconnected mode. So if you lose your connection then the application continues to run on the desktop clients.

Here is a video of me running an Access application and I switch to running this application in a browser at the half way point:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

(no ActiveX or Silverlight is required – you can even use these Access forms in your smartphone's web browser or on an iPad).

And here is another video showing how one can export "relational" data tables up to office 365 using Access.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wdjYIby_b0&fmt=22&hd=1

Note that because these published Applications run on a cloud OS, you not limited by the Access database engine and you are NOT using the Access data engine for the web published data. This means the user limit really is only that of the massive cloud servers, and they of course can handle millions of users. So Access Web services on office 365 would also be a possible solution here.